# вопрос по обработке сигналов с помощью signal в си

Tags: c, signal

Есть вот такой код. Программа представляет собой сервер получающий сообщения от клиента посредством передачи сигналов SIGUSR1 или SIGUSR2 и расшифровывающий с помощью побитовых операций (но это пока не важно). Сервер показывает PID, а затем ждет сигнала SIGUSR1 или SIGUSR2.
1.Вопрос простой:
В main в случае поступления сигнала запускается функция- обработчик ft_btoa БЕЗ АРГУМЕНТОВ. Тогда каким образом она понимает что переменная "sig" в описании функции ft_btoa это номер сигнала?
2. Вопрос - в каких случаях допускается использовать signal, а не sigaction?

```
#include "../include/minitalk.h"

void    ft_btoa(int sig)
{
    static int  bit;
    static int  i;

    if (sig == SIGUSR1)
        i |= (0x01 << bit);
    bit++;
    if (bit == 8)
    {
        ft_printf("%c", i);
        bit = 0;
        i = 0;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int pid;

    (void)argv;
    if (argc != 1)
    {
        ft_printf("Error\n");
        return (1);
    }
    pid = getpid();
    ft_printf("%d\n", pid);
    while (argc == 1)
    {
        signal(SIGUSR1, ft_btoa);
        signal(SIGUSR2, ft_btoa);
        pause ();
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: *В main в случае поступления сигнала запускается функция- обработчик ft_bt* - ничего подобного, эта функция будет вызвана рантаймом с нужным аргументом. `signal(SIGUSR1, ft_btoa);` - тут передается указатель на нее. Лучше было бы написать `signal(SIGUSR1, &ft_btoa);`

Comment: Я новичок еще в программировании. Что значит "вызвана рантаймом"?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: [man 7 signal](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) и [man 2 signal](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) читали? 1) Функция signal регистрирует обработчик, который должен соответствовать прототипу `void (*sighandler_t)(int);` (именно с этим одним аргументом он будет вызван ОС при получении сигнала) (кстати,  вызывать signal в цикле не нужно, однажды зарегистрированный обработчик никуда не денется до его переопределения новым вызовом signal). 2) [sigaction](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) это расширенный вариант signal